# Can you notify question's OP when any answer is commented?

Tags: feature-request

Currently if I ask a question and somebody answers it I am notified about this event.

However, if somebody comments on the answer, the author of the answer is notified, not the OP.

In many cases comments provide a valuable feedback to the OP as well as to the author of the answer.

Can we add OP notification for such an event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been many suggestions along this line already. My view is that it would be useful to know, as the OP:

- When an answer is edited;
- When an answer is added (done);
- When a comment is added;
- When someone edits the question;
- Arguably when a comment or answer is deleted.

As an answerer you are generally interested in:

- When the question is commented;
- When the question is edited;
- When your answer is edited;
- When your answer is selected (done);
- When your answer is deselected;

You can also make a case that an answerer could also be interested in:

- Edits to other answers;
- New other answers;
- Any answer being selected or deselected;
- Any comment.

Also you could argue that someone who is just reading the question is interested in some or all of the above. This is particularly the case when you find an interesting question that hasn't been answered yet. The only way of dealing with this currently is to favourite it and remember to go back to it, which is fairly crude.

Lastly, all of the above should be able to be treated as a subscription (ie you can unsubscribe from some/all notifications).

Comment: I already hate it when the envelope lits with the current notifications... so please add a configuration option if this is implemented

Comment: The real problem with the envelope is that a) it is triggered by community wiki events that you aren't notified of, b) it lags the actual change to the point you've already seen it before it lights up and c) it doesn't take into account whether you've already seen the event.