# View list of comments I've posted

Tags: feature-request

There have been times when I post a comment on something and I want to see what others have replied to it. It would be nice if someone replying to an answer/question you commented on triggered the mail flag to go orange or if you could see a list of comments you've posted so you can go back and check.

Comment: @ccornet Huh, didn't see that get added. Nice. If you post it as an answer I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: You could also go ahead and upvote this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/subscribing-to-questions-and-comments-that-dont-belong-to-you

Comment: You can also look at your recent activity - recent comments you made are listed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You won't get alerts for just any activity in a post you've commented on, but you will get alerts when someone specifically attempts to alert you in a comment sequence. See [this FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for more details.