# track bounty questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

I recently put a bounty on a question that I'm really interested in receiving more answers for. Trouble is, I can't remember the title of that question and I'm lazy. I thought it'd be in the 'activity' tab on my profile page, but it wasn't.

Am I looking in the wrong place or is this a feature request?

Comment: Seems ridiculous to do that. Wonder why its not in the activity log?

Comment: Offering bounties is a privilege, like voting. Ultimately, you're free to offer bounties as you see fit once you earn the privilege, just as you're welcome to cast your votes as you see fit. But in my opinion, if you're too lazy to remember a given post for seven days, you shouldn't be offering a bounty on it. So -1 because I don't want the system to encourage this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a bounty tab on the user profile page which shows all current and historical bounty activity for that user.

Answer (score 1):

ok.. you can go to the reputation page and check for a dip in your reputation, select a region around that dip and hopefully you'll recognize the question.. seems tedious, but its works.

Comment: I thought if you could clicked the star below the vote up/down it then alerts you to any activity?

Comment: interesting!.. one more way to do this. However, it kinda mixes up what I thought was meant by 'favourites' (for me)

Comment: yes, I think there is a discussion on here somewhere for it to be renamed to something like "follow question". Ah, here it is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53124/rename-favorite-questions-to-subscribed-or-following

Comment: I treat favourites -> bookmarks (in the same way as IE called bookmarks favourites.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a bounty, you should mark the question as a "favorite" by clicking the star icon beneath it's voting indicator. This means you will get notifications everytime the question is edited.