# Could we please get some way of knowing that we've placed a bounty that's still out there?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, information-display, bounties

I just got the notice of a question I'd placed a bounty on, that I'd forgot I had.  How about a line in the Profile before Questions, called Bounty.  It will list the the current question you have that you've bounty (and in the future when we're able to do more than one, it could list them all).  I'd actually gone to the featured page thinking I had a bounty, but didn't have the motivation to click on every one to see which one it was.

Another partial way would be to treat all bounties like temporary favorites, so that at least changes to them would show up in your favorites tab (and yes, I'll be favoriting all future bounties on others questions).

Comment: possible duplicate of [track bounty questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55413/track-bounty-questions)

Comment: Offering bounties is a privilege, like voting. Ultimately, you're free to offer bounties as you see fit once you earn the privilege, just as you're welcome to cast your votes as you see fit. But in my opinion, if a question isn't important enough for you to remember it for seven days, you shouldn't be offering a bounty on it. So -1 because I don't want the system to encourage this.

Comment: @Popular, I'm happy for you that you have a good memory.  Some of us aren't so lucky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is now a bounty tab on the user profile page which shows all current and historical bounty activity for that user.

Comment: oooOOOOoooh! Historical bounty!  That will be very handy for those that abuse, er *use* bounties frequently.

Answer (score 5):

How about we give a background coloring on questions that we have a bounty on in the Featured Questions list?