# Is there an easy way to get the question on which I currently have a bounty placed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we please get some way of knowing that we've placed a bounty that's still out there?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55534/could-we-please-get-some-way-of-knowing-that-weve-placed-a-bounty-thats-still-o)

I placed a bounty on a question that was not my own, and now I can't find it. Is there a quick/easy search or something I can do to find the bounty I have open?

Comment: I like that idea. Would be very useful.

Comment: @Jon: Agreed. Voted to close it myself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it with your reputation graph:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/82320/billy-oneal?tab=reputation

If you scroll down there is a red entry **-250** for [data mapper vs active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169832/data-mapper-vs-active-record)

Now that's not a solution if you frequently give out bounties. But at least it's discoverable.