# View all questions with bounties that I answered and won

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, bounties

Is there a way to view all questions that I earned a bounty on?

As per barry's comment below, check screenshot. 
[image]

Comment: This information is now available in the bounty tab - it was added in June 2011: [Could we please get some way of knowing that we've placed a bounty that's still out there?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55534)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this using the search page in Stack Overflow but I have just created a query using the Data Explorer to do this.

Enter your user Id and run the query - it will give you details of the questions that you have answered that you received a bounty amount for.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1090/bounty-amount-received-per-user

Comment: This is returning empty results.

Comment: @Hussein - The Stack Exchange Data Explorer only contains data up to the 9th Feb 2011.

Comment: I have bounties before Feb 9. But non are showing. Is this working for you..

Comment: @Hussein - It works fine for me.  Which Bounty are you missing?

Comment: @barry I'm not getting any results. I edited my question and included a screenshot. It's showing no results even though i won several bounties on SO.

Comment: @Hussein Are you absolutely sure that you have earned a bounty before Feb. 9th? I don't see any bounties awarded to you on your [reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/560735/hussein?tab=reputation) before that date. Also, note that your user IDs are different on this site and Stack Overflow.