# How about an "Open Bounty" section in our profile?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we please get some way of knowing that we've placed a bounty that's still out there?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55534/could-we-please-get-some-way-of-knowing-that-weve-placed-a-bounty-thats-still-o)

I started a bounty on another user's question. Now I can't find the damn question! Well, I did find it after some searching, but since it wasn't one that I asked or answered, it was a tad difficult to do. Also, I forgot about the bounty for a bit.

Is it possible to get a section above "Questions" in our Profile/Info that reads "Open Bounty" and only appears when we have an open bounty?

This would (1) help me find the question so I can track activity (new answers, votes, comments, etc), and (2) remind me that I have an open bounty.

Comment: If it's your first bounty on another user's question on a site you can click on the _Investor_ badge in your profile to find the question.