# New bounties tab in profile: Something bad happened!

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

I noticed a new "bounties" tab between "stats" and "accounts" in profiles on both MSO and SO.  Hurray!

Unfortunately, it crashes with the "Something bad happened!" page.

Part of it seems to be working.  In the tab title itself an open bounty is indicated with a reverse-video asterisk, e.g. in [Lance Robert's profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13295/lance-roberts):

[image: Bounties Tab]

Related:

- [How about an "Open Bounty" section in our profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95740/how-about-an-open-bounty-section-in-our-profile)
- [Could we please get some way of knowing that we've placed a bounty that's still out there?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55534/could-we-please-get-some-way-of-knowing-that-weve-placed-a-bounty-thats-still-o)

Comment: But may I add, thanks for this feature! (Assuming it works)

Comment: @PengOne I'm able to see my own bounties tab, so it does seem to work so long as I don't want to see anyone else's bounties, heh.

Comment: It works for me as well now. And the site was down a moment ago. I believe the gurus are on top of it.

Comment: For me MSO works now but SO still crashes.  I'm sure it'll be ironed out shortly.  Great feature!

Comment: Same here, it doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You know, we learned something today (and by we I mean a Tar Heel).

When code varies in behavior based on whether the viewing user is a moderator, be sure to test the "not a moderator" case.

A fix has been deployed, and this tab should be working for everyone now.

Comment: Thanks.  By including earned and past bounties, you have implemented the feature more completely than I could have hoped for.  Bravo!

Comment: @Rick - [Craver](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver) implemented it, I just fixed a (relatively minor, but rather... visible) bug.

Comment: I know this is different, but still no change to see a bounty tab on the "tag sets" page? (as described in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70967/is-it-possible-to-add-the-featured-questions-category-for-the-tag-sets)