# Bookmark-feature?

Tags: feature-request

There is one feature I would love to see included, and that was a bookmark-feature.  Something similar to the favourite-feature; but without the counting and without the implication that you found the question particular useful.

I have been using the favorite-feature to mark questions to revisit, but as I also use it to mark questions I found particularely useful (it's intended use?), things become a bit chaotic.  So it would be very useful with a seperate bookmark-function, just for questions you for some reason would like to revisit later.

Another great feature would be a follow-feature, that tracked *changes* to a question - like new answers and new comments.  It would be very useful when one encounter a *great* question with as-of-yet no answers.

Comment: People can and do favorite questions for all sorts of reasons, certainly not just because they think it's a good question.  Favoriting already does exactly what you want, just use it.  It even indicates whether the question has been changed since you last visited it.

Comment: Your *browser* has that bookmark feature already. I regularly use starring to track a post I want to keep an eye on, to revisit them later. No 'like' is implied.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/subscribing-to-questions-and-comments-that-dont-belong-to-you

Comment: I wonder if it might be useful to do a minor UI change, and rename "Favorite" to "Watching" or "Bookmark", so people don't think it implies that the person 'likes' the post, [as in this declined proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53124/rename-favorite-questions-to-subscribed-or-following)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to bookmark a question without the [system thinking you like it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question), just add it as a browser bookmark or you could use the RSS feed for the question, in the bottom right hand corner:

[image: RSS]