# Flag for "notification without commenting or answering" / monitor-button

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, notifications

I did a quick search for this feature with the question terms I used, nothing came up, but I am happy to delete this thread, if this is a duplicate (I am out for some hours now though, takes some time).

I want to suggest a button or link, for monitoring a question, without commenting or answering first. I mean to get the same notification as I would, if I had posted, but even without the need of a `@` in front of my name when commenting.

I would suggest to put the link in the row with:

```
share|edit|flag
```

**Edit:**
Ok, I just thought about the "backend" of that, there should be a link on the profile too, to find the question, even if nothing happened?!?

Any ideas on that or past decisions?

Comment: [this perhaps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/subscribing-to-questions-and-comments-that-dont-belong-to-you?rq=1)?

Comment: @OGHaza Ah, subscription, cool term, yeah I will delete this here. ;)

Comment: Don't delete the dupe, it can act as a signpost for future people who have the same idea, but can't find the original, like you did.

Comment: @3ventic Ok, undone ;)