# Getting notifications on specific question

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

I know if i answer any question and someone put comment on my answer then i get notifications or if i comment on anything and in reply i am tagged then also i get notifications.

Is this possible to get all notifications related to a question or to just start following a question. What i mean to say is if i like a question and want to keep track of all activities going on that question is this possible.

I am not able to get any option.

Comment: Have you tried using the star under the voting buttons?

Comment: @Catija No that i never tried. Will take a look on that. Thanks

Comment: @Catija You don't receive inbox notifications for activity on starred questions, though. You still have to actively check your starred question list on the profile page.

Comment: A good related one, containing links to other relevant posts as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/subscribing-to-questions-and-comments-that-dont-belong-to-you?rq=1. See also some of the other related links on the right.