# How to "unfollow" a question that I posted an answer to?

Tags: support, questions, notifications

I made a post in a sandbox question and now I get notifications about other posts.

I could not find any option to ignore notifications from that thread.
Is there no such option or did I miss it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't get inbox notifications about other answers in that thread; [there's simply no such function](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45360/295232). (FWIW, you *would have* been notified if you had *asked the question* itself.)

You got notified by [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/326540#comment1066111_326540); if you want to avoid that, you can simply delete the post and undelete it when you need it (that's what a sandbox is for).

Comment: ups - should have read more carefully