# Would it be possible to alert users or provide an information screen to users for relevant updates to posts they have upvoted or answered previously?

Tags: feature-request, voting

There is a small problem with Stack Exchange whereby new answers to an old question do not get enough votes.

If a user has upvoted a question or an answer or answered a question it usually means the user is interested in it.  Could the Stack Overflow developers create an algorithm that shows the user their top 5 most relevant updates to posts they have interacted with.  Possible ways of notifying the users would be alert them, show as an information box on the profile or home screen perhaps.

Would this be feasible?

### Edit - additional thoughts

I think there are sufficient variables to calculate a score to determine how relevant an update is to a user; such as number of likes the question has received, whether a user has commented on a question or answer, whether they posted an answer could be rated higher for instance, a randomness so that some users get notified but not all, if a new answer has is upvoted quickly then that would also increase the score.  This kind of thing would feed into itself and good questions could then be recognised more easily.

I'm not going to try to devise a scoring system but my point is that there are sufficient variables to calculate a rating to base a decision on what is relevant to the user (of course it could never be exact but it could be helpful). This score could then be fed into a form to inform the user; some suggestions:

- a top 5 relevant updates page on the SE homepage
- a once every 5 visits alert
- if the relevant score is high enough then the user will get an alert so that the users do not get flooded with updates for every single update to a single question

I think there is potential here.

Comment: I would say this question is different to the one you linked this to as a duplicate

Comment: I really think this is a good idea and not a duplicate!

Comment: Better dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/subscribing-to-questions-and-comments-that-dont-belong-to-you

Comment: I would still say these features are different but tackle the same problem - I'm not sure how the dupe system works but I'd still say this is not a dupe

Answer (score 4):

A similar feature already exists: you can favorite a question and regularly check the [Favorites tab in your profile](/users/current/?tab=favorites) for updates to the question and its answers. You're right, that depends on users actually using that feature.

> Could the Stack Overflow developers create an algorithm that shows the user their top 5 most relevant updates to posts they have interacted with.

I think the main challenge would be to write this algorithm. A small edit may be much more relevant to you (because it addresses a specific flaw) than a large one (which may offer an alternative solution even though the original version works well for you). Perhaps the number of recent upvotes would work as a metric, but that's a catch-22; the answer needs to have more attention in the first place to get those votes.

Such a filter is a requirement; I've answered and upvoted more than a thousand questions on this site; I would never be interested in seeing a list of all updates in them. That's simply too much noise to filter through.

> There is a small problem with Stack Exchange whereby new answers to an old question do not get enough votes.

New answers will bump a question to the frontpage, so they're bound to get *some* attention. If you see a really undervalued late answer, consider drawing more attention to it by posting a [bounty](/help/bounty). There's even a standard reason for this: "Reward an existing answer".

Comment: @Glofindel but users don't use it so it does not make a difference to the problem I mentioned.  Also I don't think you read my question, my feature request suggerted showing only updates for only the most relevent updates, maybe having a separate section rather than an alert

Comment: New answers will be bumped yes but the users who have liked a question or a post will not know about the update...keep an open mind at least

Comment: I'm looking at your solution from a slightly different perspective. The main problem is that the system can't determine what updates are relevant.

Comment: I would say it can, it could determine a score based on who else has liked that new answer, how many likes the question has received over time, whether you posted an answer, whether you commented on an answer or the question.  There are many variables to formulate a score.  I guess for you as an administrator it may not be as useful but for most of the users here I think it could be a really good feature.

Comment: thank you for your input.  I was a bit surprised by the backlash (-6, I've never had that before!) I think there is a challenge in writing something like this of course but sometimes that is the fun no?  It wouldn't need to be exact and one could just take the top five based on the score and show that result on an information screen.

Comment: [Voting is different on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta): *On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.*

Comment: ok, well thank you again for your thoughts.  I think the problem exists and there is not a sufficient solution to it, it would be interesting to consider some solutions I think (I would say that useful new answers don't get enough recognition).  Thank you for explaining the voting system :-)